# What test should be applied for someone that was hit by a boulder and is now hanging off a cliff?

Tags: helping

In my campaign I have a mountain with steep switchbacks where the party has boulders thrown at them from the top.  I have them rolling *reflex* to get out of the way. However, if one is hit I want them to be hanging off the cliff until help (another player) arrives to get them back up.

What would the player have to roll for under these circumstances?

Comment: Hello and welcome!  Take our [tour] and look around.  First up, there are thousands of role-playing games, so take a minute to tag your question with which one you're asking about (I assume [dnd-5e]).  Also I assume you mean "if one is hit" when you say "if one is his"?

Comment: What do you mean by "rolling reflex" and what game system/edition are you playing?  (I assume that you are applying the reflex saving throw for the attempts to avoid the rocks, but your confirmation would be appreciated.  Please clarify.)